# All stats on site stats note listed as "0"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, statistics

I was looking at the side of the page on the parent site and noticed that every single stat in the site stats was listed as 0.

[image]

I've been having some network issues so I wouldn't be surprised if this is exclusive to myself; can anyone confirm/deny the problem or explain it?

Comment: Just noticed this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59494/site-stats-zeroed-in-public-betas :<

Comment: Yes, it happened before also, it was fixed eventually

Comment: Still happens for me here.

Comment: @Arda: Juan was referring to the last time it occured when he said it was fixed.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Jeff [over here](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198/site-stats-broken), this is expected behavior that should be resolved in a matter of minutes. Gonna mark this as by design.

> This is normal -- the stats refresh is every 10 minutes, and sometimes after we deploy the timing is wrong, so the stats may say zero for the first 10 minutes.